# How to create a variable that is a piece of another variable?

Tags: sas

I would like to create a variable that is simply just part of another variable. I set the new variable equal to the original variable, and then formatted it to do what I wanted, but it still holds the value of the entire original variable. Here is my code:

```
DATA Names;
   INFILE "......." firstobs=7;
   INPUT Name $ Rank :COMMA6. @@;
   Rank=-Rank;
   FirstTwo = Name;
   Format FirstTwo $2.;
RUN;
```

I would like to make FirstTwo variable be equal to only the first two letters of Name. With the way I did it, it does not only take the first two letters, it just formats the variable to only be 2 letters. This doesn't help me because later on I would like to sort by FirstTwo, but it still sorts by Name, since FirstTwo is only a FORMAT of Name. Is there any way to make FirstTwo equal to only the first two letters of Name, rather than simply a format of the first two letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your assignment statement is  `FirstTwo = Name;`. This is why your variable FirstTwo has the same value as Name. You need to change the assignment statement. Try `FirstTwo = put(Name,$2.);`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I forgot about put(). Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could have used

```
length firstTwo $2;
firstTwo=Name;
```

Important that LENGTH statement comes before assignment.